# ASP.NET MVC JQuery Ajax function not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a function in the file Controller class called themess and I'm trying to post information back via JQuery AJAX but the event in the controller isn't firing when debugging.

The Url is http://localhost:8081/character/two

The function that supposed to be receiving and handling the code is :-

```
    public ActionResult themess(string sText)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Inserted" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When the code seems to be receiving the post, it seems to be going to the wrong function. It goes to [httpPost] function.

When I trace via Fiddler, I get

```
POST http://localhost:58281/character/two/themess HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:58281
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:58281
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:58281/character/two
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=3vhn5okbsiblowtkt34puxsf;_ga=GA1.1.513197781.1472146597; __atuvc=257%7C34%2C174%7C35%2C699%7C36%2C145%7C37; __atuvs=57dae9e7623c17f3002
```

sText=Message  (this line is attached to the above trace)

What am I missing as to why the themess isn't firing, am I supposed to put something in RouteConfig as thats all I have in it at the moment.

```
routes.MapRoute("CharacterRule", "character/{id}/{Misc}", new { Controller = "file", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
routes.MapRoute("CharacterDupRule", "character/{id}", new { Controller = "file", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

This is my Jquery Function

```
    $("#form1").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();



  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@("/file/two/themess")',
    dataType: "json",
    data: 'sText=Message',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function() {
      alert('success');
    },
    failure: function(response) {
      alert(response.d);
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to use `/character/two/themes` for your url in your ajax call? since that is what you said your URL is for your site **http://localhost:8081/character/two**

Comment: that would be ideal, the reason I put /file/two was i read somewhere about to use @Url.Action("postcomment") and thats what its roughly translated to, should use URL.Action or /character/two/themess, I'll correct and test and update.

Comment: The data you are passing isn't in json format but you are declaring it as so.

Comment: How can i format it to be Json format?  or what do I change the Content Type to?

Comment: try setting it equal to "text/plain". But better idea would be to set your data parameter to JSON.stringify({"sText" : "Message"}) and keep your contentType unchanged.

Comment: If I want to add additional parameters how would I build the JSON string with so Themess(string a, string B) ?

I have managed to call a multiparameter function using text/plain but its not deserializing the values into the parameters, any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: So when you call your C# WebMethod that has two string parameters called exactly "stringA" and "stringB" are you passing in an object like this: JSON.stringify({"stringA" : "A", "stringB":"B"})? This should work in the case you presented.

Comment: Getting a little bit further with JSON, its now doing the string :- {"gCaptcha":"","txtName":"","txtEmail":"Admin","txtMessage":""}  but the function parameter in C# is null and doesn't have Admin as the value.

Comment: can you post your C# method?

Comment: No need, its working fine now, done something, I dunno but its working now.  Here's my method header anyway :-  public ActionResult postcomment(string gCaptcha,string txtName, string txtEmail, string txtMessage)

Comment: Now need to return a value for failure, its always returning the success part.  The C# I'm using to return a value is :- return Json(new { success = false, message = sRules[0] }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);

Comment: If you have a try-catch in your WebMethod, Ajax is going to evaluate it as "success" even if your WebMethod is returning the value in the error handler unless you specify that "Response.StatusCode = 400", then AJAX will also interpret the response as a failure.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("themess","file")', // instead of  '@("/file/two/themess")',
    data: {'sText': "Message"}, // instead of 'sText=Message',
    success: function() {
      alert('success');
    },
    failure: function(response) {
      alert(response.d);
    }
  });
});
```

in case if you want to send multi data to the action, you can send them  in the data as follows:

```
data: {'paramName1': value1, 'paramName2': value2,...,'paramNameI',valueI}
```

Hope this will help you